# How tables prefixed with TempDB work? Preventing running out of memory with many temp tables

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

In [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/) article I found statement:

> Temporary tables come in different flavours including, amongst others, local temporary tables (starting with #), global temporary tables (starting with ##), persistent temporary tables (prefixed by TempDB..), and table variables.(starting with (@)

I know how tables prefixed with `#`, `##`, `@` work, but author totally ommits persistent temporary tables in the rest of the article and I can't find anything about them on other sites.

Are tables prefixed with `TempDB` stored on a hard drive? How and when use them? Are they private to the connection?

I ask about this because when I have users who simultaneously run the same query I don't want to run out of memory because of too many temporary tables created.

Comment: You can create normal tables in TempDB, they just get destroyed when SQL Server gets restarted.

Comment: @MJH What do you mean by normal? Where are they stored and how to create them.

Comment: You seem to be laboring under the popular misconception that temporary tables are *not* stored on the hard drive. They typically are, although there is a lot of cleverness with caching to minimize overhead of (re)-creating them. A table in tempdb that does not have a special prefix is no different from a table created in any other database, but neither is tempdb "in memory".

Comment: The article has at least two sections about tables created in `TempDB`. And `You’re unlikely to want to do this, but it is certainly possible since TempDB is just another database.`

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ok then the tables prefixed with `#` are also stored on a hard drive? Another thing are all tables in `TempDB` are private to a connection?

Comment: @Yoda why are you looking for "persistent temporary tables"? You don't get any performance benefit by creating tables in TempDB instead of a normal database. You won't get "fast" staging tables for example. You get a *lot* of problems though, as `tempdb` is used by the entire server as a sandbox, tables, indexes and statistics get lost upon restart etc

Comment: The scope of temp tables is basic stuff, explained in the [documentation itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql). Tables that are not prefixed with `#` are *not* temporary tables. If you create them in tempdb, they're just regular tables that happen to be in tempdb, and no special scoping rules apply to them. Calling them "temporary tables", like the linked article does, is just misleading. They're temporary in the sense that tempdb is recreated on restart, but the tables themselves are not.

Comment: @Yoda `tempdb` is just a database. **Why** do you ask though? In-memory tables are available, but are *not* meant to "speed up" bad queries. SQL Server already does a good job of buffering. If you have a slow query, optimize it. If you want to create staging tables, do so in a normal database, possibly saving them in separate filegroups, on separate disks. If you need help with a query, post the query, its execution plan, the table schemas and indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am afraid of running out of RAM when many users cause running the same stored procedure that creates temporary tables, so I ask about private to the connection stored on hard drive tables.

Comment: Temp tables do not cause any special pressure on memory. Can you run out of memory when many users simultaneously produce loads of data? Sure. Is that specifically related to temp tables? No, because if you had all those users create non-temp tables, or share one big non-temp table, you'd have the same issue. Typically you worry about running out of *disk space* for tempdb. Again, tempdb is not an in-memory database! (Yet.)

Comment: @Yoda why would a stored procedure called by a lot of users need to create temporary tables at all? I could understand an ETL sproc (still a very bad idea) but a *common* stored procedure shouldn't have to use temporary storage. Why do you care about *RAM* anyway, which is managed by SQL Server itself? If you have a problem with the stored procedures, optimize them.

Comment: @Yoda fix the bad query instead of trying to "fix" non-existent memory problems.

Comment: Stop using temp tables. I see this all the time - SQL works best when you use the query language that powers it, if you are using temp tables you are probably doing something wrong unless you are adamant you know what you are doing. Temp tables are a crutch for the person that can't write a query - people find it easier to break things into small steps instead of writing structured, fast T-SQL

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks, that solves my problem.

Comment: @Charleh Real, living software that evolves for 5,10,15 years created by hundreds of people needs diverse approaches during its transformation to support new technology, it never happens in one go and has many intermediate stages, it's not isolated example of best programming practices.

Comment: @Charleh breaking down complex queries to use temp tables is often a good idea. it allows statistics and indexes to be created on intermediate results. See the SqlCat team advice here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2013/09/09/when-to-break-down-complex-queries/

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not saying "stop using temp tables" (well I did say that) - I probably should amend to "stop using temp tables irresponsibly" hence the disclaimer ("unless you are adamant you know what you are doing") - I've seen it too many times - queries that select the whole of a huge table into a freshly created, non-indexed heap and then try to do a load of processing/updating/deleting to get to the result set, thrashing tempDB/disk and the log where a simple optimised query would work a million times better.

Answer (score 0):

You can create "normal" tables in TempDB:

```
use tempdb

create table MyTable (
    id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    name varchar(200) not null
)
```

The tables will persist until SQL Server is re-started.